# I cannot build and install QEMU for RISCV

Tags: qemu, riscv

I try to install the toolchain of QEMU for risc-v so I follow  this tuto  https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/wiki but i get this error:

```
aitmanss@lo-lester-032:~/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/riscv-qemu$  make install
    CHK version_gen.h
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/share/doc/qemu"
install -c -m 0644 qemu-doc.html  qemu-tech.html "/usr/local/share/doc/qemu"
install: impossible de supprimer '/usr/local/share/doc/qemu/qemu-doc.html': Permission non accordée
install: impossible de supprimer '/usr/local/share/doc/qemu/qemu-tech.html': Permission non accordée
make: *** [Makefile:437: install-doc] Error 1
```

this part I change the permission but got this error

```
aitmanss@lo-lester-032:~/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/riscv-qemu$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/doc/qemu/qemu-doc.html
aitmanss@lo-lester-032:~/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/riscv-qemu$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/doc/qemu/qemu-tech.html 
aitmanss@lo-lester-032:~/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/riscv-qemu$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/doc/qemu
aitmanss@lo-lester-032:~/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/riscv-qemu$  make install
    CHK version_gen.h
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/share/doc/qemu"
install: impossible de modifier les droits de « /usr/local/share/doc/qemu »: Opération non permise
make: *** [Makefile:436: install-doc] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors shown in the console output indicate that you don't have permissions to write to directories where you're trying to install QEMU.

Usually you can first build software and then install it. This is definitely the case with QEMU.

You can build it in your home directory as an ordinary user. Building step does not need any privileges. When you install it under /usr/local you can do it with root privileges, e.g. using `sudo make install`. Alternatively you can configure it with `--prefix` pointing somewhere where you have write access, then you'll be able to install it as an ordinary user.